# Use VBA to get value of specific control in report?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I can't remember for the life of me how to use Access VBA to get the value of a specific control in a report.

My report has multiple rows (it contains a table with the results of a query). I want to be able to double-click on a field in one row and open up a separate form containing the results of a second query. Those results should be based on a WHERE clause containing the text of the field that was originally double-clicked.

If I use Me.ControlName.Value, my second report is using every record in the first report. How do I tell it to use only the record that was double-clicked?

Answer (score 1):

Use the *WhereCondition* option for `DoCmd.OpenReport` to filter the second report's recordset based on the double-clicked field in the first report.

The following example was tested with your sample db file in Access 2007.  The report text box *Fruit* has a double-click event procedure which creates a *WhereCondition* string based on the value of the text box and then calls `OpenReport` with that string ...

```vb
Private Sub Fruit_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
    Dim strWhere As String
    strWhere = "[Fruit]='" & Me.Fruit.Value & "'"
    Debug.Print strWhere
    DoCmd.OpenReport ReportName:="rptLabel", _
        View:=acViewPreview, WhereCondition:=strWhere
End Sub
```

Comment: That's still cycling through every record in the report, not just the one that is clicked on. Only the record clicked on shows up in the debug messages, but it's trying to output the second report for every record, not just the one clicked.

Comment: It's as if the WHERE clause isn't being included at all. I've verified that it's correct (if I manually use it in a query, the WHERE clause works fine).

Comment: I don't know why it's failing.  I tested that code with a form in Access 2007.  Add `Option Explicit` to the Declarations section of your form's module, then run Debug->Compile from the VB Editor's main menu.  Do you get a compile error?

Comment: No compile error. I am using reports instead of forms. Should I try using forms instead?

The purpose of this little project is to take a list of open service records and provide the ability to double-click on a record and open a second report (or form) that auto-generates a printable label from the service record's data.

Comment: I don't believe form vs. report makes a difference because both `OpenForm` and `OpenReport` include the *WhereCondition* option.  There must be another implementation detail which differs between your attempt and mine, but I can't tell you where to look.  If you upload a copy of your db to a file sharing site and provide a link, I'll try to spot the problem.

Comment: The database I'm working on is internal-only, but I made a test database and it's doing the same thing. Here's my test DB: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zwllgtasms95fx6/test.accdb